# Two iCloud accounts on one Mac using Sierra

Tags: mac, macos, user-account

I share a Macbook Pro with my partner.  We have our own user account on the Mac which we sign into whenever we want to use it.  We also have our own iCloud accounts.

However when I sign into iCloud whilst logged in with my Mac account, it also signs into iCloud for my partner's Mac account.  In other words it seems as though I can only have 1 iCloud account on a Mac.  Is this true?

We have setup a Family within iCloud where I am the organizer and my partner is another user.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by _when I sign into iCloud whilst logged in with my Mac account, it also signs into iCloud for my partner's Mac account_? Is it signing into _their_ iCloud account or into _your_ iCloud account?

Comment: So if I go to System Prefs > iCloud, I see my iCloud account.  I see my iCloud account for both local user accounts on the Mac.  It doesn't seem to be possible to have separate iCloud accounts for each local user account.